# How to denote a one-hot vector space, like $\mathbb{R}^n$ but for one-hot vectors?

Tags: notation, vectors, article-writing

For real vector $v_r$ we can write $v_r \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

For binary vector $v_b$, I think we can write $v_b \in \{0,1\}^n$.

But how should we write a [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) vector $v_i$?

Comment: Do you mean a vector in $\{0,1\}$ in which only one component is a $1$? That's what I understand from the wikipedia page "One-hot" when I googled "hot vector space"

Comment: @Sambo yes, I mean that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could denote the set of one-hot vectors by:

$$
\left\{
v \in \{0,1\}^n : 
\sum \limits_{i=1}^n v_i = 1
\right\}
$$

Comment: If I only want to denote a single vector, can I drop the outer brackets? Does the summing condition still work in this case?

Comment: Sure; in that case I'd replace the colon by an "and".